# Write string of escaped byte characters, ie '\x00\x20\...', as if they were bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am playing around with .wav file generation and have functions to convert base 10 integer into hexadecimal. I need to write these hex numbers as if they were bytes, not simply encoding them to be written as bytes. I can hard code using escape sequences but I need to use strings provided by my functions.

My temporary work around makes use of eval as follows.

```
eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(16, 32))) + "'")
```

What is a more preferred method to accomplish this task without eval?

Here is some code to better understand the situation.

```
with open('song.wav', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ChunkID)
    f.write(ChunkSize)
    f.write(Format)
    f.write(Subchunk1ID)
    f.write(Subchunk1Size)
    f.write(AudioFormat)
    f.write(NumChannels)
    f.write(SampleRate)
    f.write(ByteRate)
    f.write(BlockAlign)
    f.write(BitsPerSample)
    f.write(Subchunk2ID)
    f.write(Subchunk2Size)
    f.write(Data)
```

Using hard coded values works fine.

```
ChunkID = b'RIFF'               #big        1
ChunkSize = b'\x1a\xea\xc4\x00'     #little     2
Format = b'WAVE'                #big        3
Subchunk1ID = b'fmt '               #big        4
Subchunk1Size = b'\x10\x00\x00\x00'         #little     5
AudioFormat = b'\x01\x00'           #little     6
NumChannels = b'\x02\x00'           #little     7
SampleRate = b'\x22\x56\x00\x00'        #little     8
ByteRate = b'\x88\x58\x01\x00'          #little     9
BlockAlign = b'\x04\x00'            #little     10
BitsPerSample = b'\x10\x00'         #little     11
Subchunk2ID = b'data'               #big        12
Subchunk2Size = b'\x10\xb1\x02\x00'     #little     13
Data = b''                  #little     14
```

I need more flexibility and need similar results using functions.

```
def tohex(val, nbits):
    a = hex((val + (1 << nbits)) % (1 << nbits))
    pad = nbits/4 - (len(a) - 2)
    for i in range(0, pad):
        a = a[:2] + '0' + a[2:]
    return a
def bytestring(hexstring):
    hexstring = hexstring[2:]
    bstring = ''
    for i in range(0, len(hexstring)/2):
        bstring += '\\x'
        bstring += hexstring[2*i: 2*i+2]
    return bstring
def endian(bstring):
    return '\\'+'\\'.join(reversed(bstring.split('\\'))).rstrip('\\')
```

This is how I call the functions

```
sample_rate = 44100
channels = 2
sample_bits = 16
sample_count = 176400

ChunkID = b'RIFF'
Format = b'WAVE'
Subchunk1ID = b'fmt '
Subchunk1Size = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(16, 32))) + "'")    #n bit samples : tohex(n,m)
AudioFormat = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(1, 16))) + "'")       #uncompressed when n=1
NumChannels = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(channels, 16))) + "'")        #n channels
SampleRate = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(sample_rate, 32))) + "'")
BitsPerSample = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(sample_bits, 16))) + "'")
ByteRate = eval("b'" +  endian(bytestring(tohex(sample_rate*channels*sample_bits/8, 32))) + "'")
BlockAlign = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(channels*sample_bits/8, 16))) + "'")
Subchunk2ID = b'data'
Subchunk2Size = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(sample_count*channels*sample_bits/8, 32))) + "'")
ChunkSize = eval("b'" + endian(bytestring(tohex(36 + sample_count*channels*sample_bits/8, 32))) + "'")
Data = b''

for i in range(0, 176400): #Just test samples
    if i % 32 < 16:
        Data += b'\x10\xe7\x10\xe7'
    else:
        Data += b'\xf0\xa8\xf0\xa8'
```

Update: I added a new function to handle previous formatting and return a form I can write directly to file. The solution I marked makes use of bytes but in python 2.7 I had to use bytearray.

```
def barray(bstring):
    hexmap = {'0':0, '1':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7,'8':8, '9':9, 'a':10, 'b':11, 'c':12, 'd':13, 'e':14, 'f':15}
    bstring = bstring.lstrip('\\x')
    bstring = bstring.split('\\x')
    bstring = map(lambda x: 16*hexmap[x[0]]+hexmap[x[1]], bstring)
    return bytearray(bstring)
```

Now after I call the functions the data is ready to write to file without using eval().

```
variable = barray(endian(bytestring(tohex(n, m))))
```

Comment: You mean you want to write a byte `00`, then `20`, rather than a backslash, an `x` then a `0` and another `0`? Can you show us your *input data*? Your work-around is certainly not the way go.

Comment: What are `tohex()` and `endian` here? Did you know about the `binascii` module, and the `chr()` function? Or are you looking for the `struct` module?

Comment: Hard coding works fine: `AudioFormat = b'\x01\x00'`. When I write this to file and open a hex editor I can see 01 00. If I get `\x01\x00` as output from a function I need this treated as `b'\x01\x00'`. My apologies as I am having trouble finding the correct terms to express myself.

Comment: What is the format of the data you *actually have*, and what output do you expect to form from it?

Comment: You appear to be reinventing the [`wave` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html). At the very least [look at the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cfd768814ca3/Lib/wave.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `bytes`?

```
data = '\x00\x20\x10'
newdata = [int(i) for i in data.encode()]
print(newdata)
>>> [0, 32, 16]
print(bytes(newdata))
>>> b'\x00 \x10'  # it only looks like the middle value is missing, it isn't
print([i for i in b'\x00 \x10'])
>>> [0, 32, 16]  # yep, all still there
```

Edited based on a better understanding of the question after it was clarified.

Comment: I have not tried using an array for bytes. I think this is what I am looking for. I appreciate your prompt reply, I will update my progress later tonight when I have more time.

Comment: I hope it does what you need.  The second like where I use int() is important because int() has no problem reading the hex values when written as '\x12' or whatever.  Then use bytes on the array of integers.

Comment: I am currently using python 2.7 where this does not work for all possible data. In python 2.7 bytearray has this functionality. This is just what I needed.